# Worksheet_Change Event Crashing Excel With Live Data Feed

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling

I am attempting to run code that is driven by a `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)` event.  I want my code to analyze the data as it feeds in real time rather than having to input a big block of data every 15-20 minutes to analyze the new data.

The data I am attempting to run is fed in through an API from a data service and streams live into my excel sheet.  I use a function called `CMED.MA` which has two different parameters (irrelevant at the current moment).  It feeds in rolling down the rows so you'd have one row, then new data would feed in the next row, etc, etc.  At times it's fairly rapid (every few seconds)...other times it's very stagnant (every few minutes or so).  **Note:** The data is fed in a **single row** at a time.

I created a bunch of functions to use and stored them in a separate module (all `Public Functions`) in order to keep the worksheet module clean and short.

**Problem**

After writing a small piece of it to cover analysis of the live data I wanted to test it (thankfully decided to test it) and now when I attempt to make the code go live in the worksheet module it crashes excel entirely.  I have to shut off the data feed from the source so that I can disable the code in the worksheet module.  Any ideas or glaring issues with my code?  This is my first attempt at using a `Worksheet_Change` event

**Worksheet Module Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim initialTradeStructure As String, finalTradeStructure As String, rawStructure As String

    'RFQs
    If target.Item(1, 3) = "RequestForQuote" Then

        'Do Nothing....no analysis of RFQs is necessary....will be filtered later

    'Screen Trades
    ElseIf target.Item(1, 3) = "GlobexTrades" Then

        rawStructure = target.Item(1, 2)

        initialTradeStructure = Right(rawStructure, Len(rawStructure) - 4)

        'Bulk of analaysis conducted in analsyis engine to keep worksheet code clean/short
        finalTradeStructure = OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(initialTradeStructure, target)

    'Block screen represented as Multileg in datafeed structure
    ElseIf target.Item(1, 3) = "Block" Then

        If target.Item(1, 17) = "TRUE" Then

            rawStructure = target.Item(1, 2)

            initialTradeStructure = Right(rawStructure, Len(rawStructure) - 4)

            'Bulk of analysis conducted in analysis engine to keep worksheet code clean/short
            finalTradeStructure = OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(initialTradeStructure, target)

        ElseIf target.Item(1, 17) = "FALSE" And target.Item(1, 16) = "FALSE" Then

            'Live block trade

        Else

            'Do Nothing....No analysis of single block legs is necessary

        End If

    End If

    If Not finalTradeStructure = "Nothing" Then

        target.Item(1, 1) = finalTradeStructure

    End If

End Sub
```

**Function Module**

```
Public Function OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(tradeStructure As String, tradeDataRange As Range) As String
    'analyzes and translates tradeStructure and dataRange
    'Driver
    Dim structureAssemblyString As String, optionType As String

    'Tests for / in tradeStructure to determine if it's a LIVE option trade or if it's a multi leg structure
    If InStr(1, tradeStructure, "/") < 1 Then

        'Declares LIVE and option Type
        structureAssemblyString = "LIVE " & GetOptionCodes(Mid(tradeStructure, 8, 2)) & " " & TranslateExpirationDate(Mid(tradeStructure, 11, 6)) _
        & " " & GetCallOrPut(Mid(tradeStructure, 18, 1))

    Else

        'Place holder for multileg structures
        structureAssemblyString = "Nothing"

    End If

    OptionStructureAnalysisEngine = structureAssemblyString

End Function

Public Function GetOptionCodes(optionType As String) As String

    Select Case optionType

        Case "LO"

            GetOptionCodes = "WTI American"

        Case "OH"

            GetOptionCodes = "HO American"

        Case "OB"

            GetOptionCodes = "RB American"

        Case "LN"

            GetOptionCodes = "NG European"

    End Select

End Function

Public Function TranslateExpirationDate(expirationDate As Double) As String

    Select Case Right(expirationDate, 2)

        Case 1

            TranslateExpirationDate = "F" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 2

            TranslateExpirationDate = "G" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 3

            TranslateExpirationDate = "H" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 4

            TranslateExpirationDate = "J" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 5

            TranslateExpirationDate = "K" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 6

            TranslateExpirationDate = "M" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 7

            TranslateExpirationDate = "N" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 8

            TranslateExpirationDate = "Q" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 9

            TranslateExpirationDate = "U" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 10

            TranslateExpirationDate = "V" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 11

            TranslateExpirationDate = "X" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

        Case 12

            TranslateExpirationDate = "Z" & Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)

    End Select

End Function

Public Function GetCallOrPut(legOption As String) As String
    'Translates C to Call and P to Put in option Structure

    If legOption = "C" Then

        GetCallOrPut = "Call"

    ElseIf legOption = "P" Then

        GetCallOrPut = "Put"

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: If this is in the middle of processing when new data is fed, it seems like Excel wouldn't like that much. You would be triggering the event in the middle of the event. Never tested specifically.

Comment: @Kyle How do you mean?  I tested the use of the event data feed by highlighting rows with certain keywords in the worksheet module and it worked fine.  It's actually how I discovered that it feeds in by single rows.  I tested this with MsgBox as well and it worked through each iteration.  Even held the following data input until i had clicked ok on the MSG box for that first event.

Comment: fwiw, `Right(expirationDate, 2)` cannot be equal to `1`, it **can** however be equal to `"1"`. `CInt(Right(expirationDate, 2))` would be more appropriate.

Comment: `application.enableevents = false` is your friend. See [Application.EnableEvents property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx)

Comment: It would be prudent to check any possible conditions that match a data update. Perhaps the number of cells in a typical Target.

Comment: @Jeeped I'll make that change (to the case statement)! stupid mistake I've known that in the past.  Thanks for pointing it out! I'm unsure of the last comment though.  How can I check any/all conditions that could arise from the data update?

Comment: Try debug.print target.rows(1).cells.count as the first line within the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro. IDK if that is appropriate but you need to find some property of the data pull that can identify when to engage the worksheet_change and when to ignore it even if that is only 99% of the time.

Comment: @Jeeped input the debug line and it's printing 18 repetitively in the Immediate window.  The data no matter what is always 18 columns wide in the same columns.  The if statements i have in the worksheet module determine if it runs through the rest of the code or not so it sort of moderates the rest of the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123812/discussion-between-stormsedge-and-jeeped).

Comment: Would a change event making a change to a cell in the current target range initiate a new event?

Comment: Yes - your `target.item(1,1) = ` is the culprit.

Comment: As it is currently set up, assuming the data feed fills a cell at a time, your code just wipes out the value the data feed inserts and often locks up Excel.

Comment: Would it be more sensible only to check a row once the feed starts populating the next row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see your data nor see how these subs and functions interact with them but this is my blind rewrite on your problem. I also rewrote one of your functions to make it a little more readable (to me).

**Sheet1 - Code Sheet**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Rows(1).Cells.Count = 18 Then
        'set a custom error procedure; essentially revert to as normal as ppossible
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        'turn off event handling so if anything is changed, the sub procedure does not try to walk on top of itself
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'only dim things now that you know that something is actually going to happen
        Dim iTS As String, fTS As String, rS As String
        'always determine text comparisons as case-insensitive
        Select Case LCase(Target.Cells(1, 3).Value2)
            caae "requestforquote"
                'do nothing
            caae "globextrades"
                rS = Target.Cells(1, 2).Value2
                initialTritsadeStructure = Right(rS, Len(rS) - 4)
                'Bulk of analaysis conducted in analsyis engine to keep worksheet code clean/short
                fTS = OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(iTS, Target)
                'Block screen represented as Multileg in datafeed structure
            caae "block"
                'Is this actually TRUE/FALSE or text...????!!!?????
                Select Case UCase(Target.Item(1, 17).Text)
                    Case "TRUE"
                        rS = Target.Item(1, 2).Value2
                        iTS = Right(rS, Len(rS) - 4)
                    Case "FALSE"
                        'Bulk of analysis conducted in analysis engine to keep worksheet code clean/short
                        fTS = OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(iTS, Target.Cells(1, 1)) '<~~ need to know which of a typical target's 18 cells to throw into this
                    Case Else
                        'do nothing
                End Select
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    End If

    If Not fTS = "Nothing" And CBool(Len(fTS)) Then
        Target.Item(1, 1) = fTS
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Module1 code sheet**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(tradeStructure As String, tradeDataRange As Range) As String
    'analyzes and translates tradeStructure and dataRange
    'Driver
    Dim structureAssemblyString As String, optionType As String

    'Tests for / in tradeStructure to determine if it's a LIVE option trade or if it's a multi leg structure
    If InStr(1, tradeStructure, "/") < 1 Then
        'Declares LIVE and option Type
        structureAssemblyString = "LIVE " & GetOptionCodes(Mid(tradeStructure, 8, 2)) & " " & TranslateExpirationDate(Mid(tradeStructure, 11, 6)) _
                                    & " " & GetCallOrPut(Mid(tradeStructure, 18, 1))
    Else
        'Place holder for multileg structures
        structureAssemblyString = "Nothing"
    End If

    OptionStructureAnalysisEngine = structureAssemblyString

End Function

Public Function GetOptionCodes(optionType As String) As String

    Select Case UCase(optionType)
        Case "LO"
            GetOptionCodes = "WTI American"
        Case "OH"
            GetOptionCodes = "HO American"
        Case "OB"
            GetOptionCodes = "RB American"
        Case "LN"
            GetOptionCodes = "NG European"
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select

End Function

Public Function TranslateExpirationDate(expirationDate As Long) As String
    Dim c As Integer, str As String
    c = CInt(Right(expirationDate, 2))
    str = Mid(expirationDate, 3, 2)
    Select Case c
        Case 1, 2, 3
            TranslateExpirationDate = Chr(c + 69) & str
        Case 4, 5
            TranslateExpirationDate = Chr(c + 70) & str
        Case 6, 7
            TranslateExpirationDate = Chr(c + 71) & str
        Case 8
            TranslateExpirationDate = Chr(c + 72) & str
        Case 9, 10
            TranslateExpirationDate = Chr(c + 76) & str
        Case 11
            TranslateExpirationDate = Chr(c + 77) & str
        Case 12
            TranslateExpirationDate = Chr(c + 78) & str
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
End Function

Public Function GetCallOrPut(legOption As String) As String
    Select Case UCase(legOption)
        Case "C"
            GetCallOrPut = "Call"
        Case "P"
            GetCallOrPut = "Put"
        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select
End Function
```

As mentioned, I did this blind. If you cannot use it or modify it to your own purposes, edit your original question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (redact your sample data as necessary).

Answer (score 0):

The line saying

```
target.Item(1, 1) = finalTradeStructure
```

is probably causing an infinite loop, as it will fire a new Change event if it is executed.

I recommend you just watch a single column (not the one that you might modify), e.g.:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    Dim initialTradeStructure As String, finalTradeStructure As String, rawStructure As String

    'See if the change affects something in column 3 and only process if it does
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then

        With Target.Rows(1)
            'RFQs
            If .Cells(1, "D") = "RequestForQuote" Then

                'Do Nothing....no analysis of RFQs is necessary....will be filtered later

            'Screen Trades
            ElseIf .Cells(1, "D") = "GlobexTrades" Then

                rawStructure = .Cells(1, "C")

                initialTradeStructure = Right(rawStructure, Len(rawStructure) - 4)

                'Bulk of analaysis conducted in analsyis engine to keep worksheet code clean/short
                finalTradeStructure = OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(initialTradeStructure, target)

            'Block screen represented as Multileg in datafeed structure
            ElseIf .Cells(1, "D") = "Block" Then

                If .Cells(1, "R") = "TRUE" Then

                    rawStructure = .Cells(1, "C")

                    initialTradeStructure = Right(rawStructure, Len(rawStructure) - 4)

                    'Bulk of analysis conducted in analysis engine to keep worksheet code clean/short
                    finalTradeStructure = OptionStructureAnalysisEngine(initialTradeStructure, target)

                ElseIf .Cells(1, "R") = "FALSE" And .Cells(1, "Q") = "FALSE" Then

                    'Live block trade

                Else

                    'Do Nothing....No analysis of single block legs is necessary

                End If

            End If

            If Not finalTradeStructure = "Nothing" Then

                .Cells(1, "B") = finalTradeStructure

            End If

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Note: I have changed your `Target.Items(1,x)` format to be `Target.Rows(1).Cells(1,x+1)` format (with the x+1 being coded as the actual alphabetic column name) as I think it will make it easier to see which columns are being referred to.